# Using a variable in a MS Access query in a C program

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, ms-access, variables, insert

I am writing a small C (.c file) app that connects to an OPC server client then outputs the data into a MS Access database.

I need to get the query to work while using a variable. My query is:

```
"INSERT INTO Data ( [Date / Time], [Hot Strip Mill rate], [Hot Strip Mill Comm Okay], [Hot Strip Mill Total] )  SELECT #variable1# AS Expr1, variable2 AS Expr2, 1 AS Expr3, variable2 AS Expr4;";
```

Variable 1 will be a datetime value and variables 2/3 will be numbers. I plan to assign the values retrieved from the OPC client to variables 1,2,3. I want/need for my query to recognize the values that the variables represent. 
So the action should go as follows: the code sees

```
 "INSERT INTO Data ( [Date / Time], [Hot Strip Mill rate], [Hot Strip Mill Comm Okay], [Hot Strip Mill Total] )  SELECT #variable1# AS Expr1, variable2 AS Expr2, 1 AS Expr3, variable2 AS Expr4;";
```

Access sees

```
"INSERT INTO Data ( [Date / Time], [Hot Strip Mill rate], [Hot Strip Mill Comm Okay], [Hot Strip Mill Total] )  SELECT #07/01/2011 04:02:01# AS Expr1, 1 AS Expr2, 14.54 AS Expr3, 64546.14 AS Expr4;";
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
#include <windows.h>

#include <stdio.h>

#include <sqlext.h>

#include <sstream>

/* Data Access Method used in this sample */
const char* DAM = "Direct ODBC";

/* Connection string for Direct ODBC */
char szDSN[256] =     "Dsn=Gas_meter_check";

main()
{
HENV    hEnv;
HDBC    hDbc;

/* ODBC API return status */
RETCODE rc;
char date[256]= "2/1/1900 23:35:45";
double var2=46;
double var3=168736;
int     iConnStrLength2Ptr;
char    szConnStrOut[256];
int i= 0;

unsigned char* InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO Data ( [Date / Time], [Hot Strip Mill rate], [Hot Strip Mill Comm Okay], [Hot Strip Mill Total] ) SELECT #***date***# AS Expr1, ***var2*** AS Expr2, ***var3*** AS Expr3, 345464 AS Expr4;";

SQLCHAR         chval1[128], chval2[128], colName[128];
int             ret1;
int             ret2;

/* Number of rows and columns in result set */
SQLINTEGER      rowCount = 0;
SQLSMALLINT     fieldCount = 0, currentField = 0;
HSTMT           hStmt;

/* Allocate an environment handle */
rc = SQLAllocEnv(&hEnv);
/* Allocate a connection handle */
rc = SQLAllocConnect(hEnv, &hDbc);

/* Connect to the TakeCharge database */
rc = SQLDriverConnect(hDbc, NULL, (unsigned char*)szDSN, 
    SQL_NTS, (unsigned char*)szConnStrOut, 
    255, (SQLSMALLINT*)&iConnStrLength2Ptr, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);
if (SQL_SUCCEEDED(rc)) 
{
    printf("%s: Successfully connected to database. Data source name: \n  %s\n", 
       DAM, szConnStrOut);

    /* Prepare SQL query */
    printf("%s: SQL InsertQuery:\n  %s\n", DAM, InsertQuery);

    rc = SQLAllocStmt(hDbc,&hStmt);
    rc = SQLPrepare(hStmt, InsertQuery, SQL_NTS);

    /* Excecute the query and create a record set */
    rc = SQLExecute(hStmt); 
    if (SQL_SUCCEEDED(rc)) 
    {
       printf("Executing query...");
       printf("\n");
        }

        while (SQL_SUCCEEDED(rc)) 
        {
            printf(" insert passed\n");
            rc = SQLFetch(hStmt);
            rowCount++;
        };         
    }
else
{
    printf("%s: Couldn't connect to %s.\n", DAM, szDSN);
}

/* Disconnect*/
SQLDisconnect(hDbc);


printf("%s: Cleanup. Done.\n", DAM);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `INSERT ... SELECT` instead of `INSERT ... VALUES ()`?

Comment: I tried that but it failed for some reason. I created the query wizard in MS Access 2010, and this is what it produced so I just decided to just stick with it. Not to be a jerk, but that wasn't really helpful to answering my question.

Comment: Well, your question is not really clear. You don't provide a error message, you don't really say whats wrong and you are posting the same question for the second time.

Comment: I posted it twice because it had the wrong tags, but the problem was that I am unsure how to input the values of that are fetched from the PLC tags and input them into my variables so that I can later pass them into my query. I hope that makes more sense. Thanks

Comment: Please properly [indent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) code for readability. The [code sample](http://sscce.org/) is neither complete nor correct as you refer to undefined variables (e.g. `input_var1`) and don't make use of the date in the query that you say that you need.

Answer (score 1):

To handle variable values in statements, use [statement parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711808.aspx). You bind a value to
a parameter using [`SQLBindParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms710963.aspx). Note parameters are not allowed in a SELECT list, so you'll need to work with `INSERT ... VALUES`. To start with, try:

```
unsigned char* InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO Data ( [Date / Time], [Hot Strip Mill rate], [Hot Strip Mill Comm Okay], [Hot Strip Mill Total] ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, 345464);";
...
    rc = SQLPrepare(hStmt, InsertQuery, SQL_NTS);

    SQLSMALLINT sqlType, decDigits, nullable;
    SQLULEN paramSize;

    SQLDescribeParam(hStmt, 1, &sqlType, &paramSize, &decDigits, &nullable);
    SQLBindParameter(hStmt, 1, 
                     SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, sqlType,
                     0 /* ignored for timestamps */, decDigits,
                     (SQLPOINTER)&date, strlen(date), NULL);

    SQLDescribeParam(hStmt, 2, &sqlType, &paramSize, &decDigits, &nullable);
    SQLBindParameter(hStmt, 2, 
                     SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_DOUBLE, sqlType,
                     paramSize, decDigits,
                     (SQLPOINTER)&rate, 0 /* ignored */, NULL);

    SQLDescribeParam(hStmt, 3, &sqlType, &paramSize, &decDigits, &nullable);
    SQLBindParameter(hStmt, 3, 
                     SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_DOUBLE, sqlType,
                     paramSize, decDigits,
                     (SQLPOINTER)&commOkay, 0 /* ignored */, NULL);

    rc = SQLExecute(hStmt);
```

As in the sample code, I haven't bothered with error handling.

Comment: I am not quite sure that I understand exactly how this works. In the place of the ?s am I supposed to input the date_time, rate, and commOkay? Stupid question but is TIMESTAMP_STRUCT date_time a struct? So I should be a struct for each variable, following the structure below:

Struct TIMESTAMP_STRUCT
char date_time

struct HSM_Values
double rate
double commOkay

Comment: Leave the `?` as they are. They are placeholders that the ODBC driver will bind to the actual values when the statement is executed. Did you read the "statement parameters" link? As for `TIMESTAMP_STRUCT`, if you search MSDN the second result is the [C Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714556.aspx) page, which describes its structure. The `SQLBindParameter` documentation (make sure you read it, too) also links to the same page in the section on the `ValueType` argument. Note that in the current sample, a string is used rather than `TIMESTAMP_STRUCT`.

Comment: Rather than re-ask the question I decided to edit the question. The actions of my code had to be change so rather than an insert, I am performing an update which should not affect the additions that you thought that I should add. They too have been added to the code; however I could not see the lines that you wrote about TIMESTAMP_STRUCT so  I am unsure if I wrote that correctly. Also, the date_time part bc as you can see the update will place it into the most recent row. I really hope that you can still help me. Thank you

Comment: @Dante: the change you made means you're now asking about a different issue, which merits a new question. The main problem I see with the current code is you're trying to bind parameters before preparing the statement. Note in my code sample the binding happens in between preparing & executing the statement.

Comment: I will request this as new question. Thank you.